# Symfony 3: UniqueEntity(errorPath) not working

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms, unique-constraint

I have an entity called **ClassSubject**  and you can see it bellow,

```
 /**
 * ClassSubject
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="class_subject")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PIE10Bundle\Repository\ClassSubjectRepository")
 * 
 * @UniqueEntity(   fields={"class", "subjects"},
 *                  errorPath="subjects",
 *                  message="This subject is already added"
 *              )
 */
class ClassSubject
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $class;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subject_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $subjects;
```

as you can see, I want to make this Unique Entity so I am [following this guide.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#errorpath)

Further I have added the followings to the top of the entity file,

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; 
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
```

After all when I submit data it still adds duplicating rows to the table. For an example,

if the table exists with a row like, **class=clsA and subjects=subA** and if I try to insert with same values, it inserts data with no validation/message "This subject is already added"

My controller is like below,

```
public function addTeacherSubjectAction( $id, Request $request )
{
    $em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user       = $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Users')->find($id);
    $subjects   = $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Subject')->findAll();

    $form       = $this->createForm(ClassSubjectType::class,$subjects);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
    {
        $allSubjects = $form['subject']->getData();
        foreach( $allSubjects as $subject )
        {
            $subject_repo   = $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Subject')->find($subject->getId());

            $teacherSubject = new TeacherSubjects();
            $teacherSubject->setTeachers($user);
            $teacherSubject->setSubjects($subject_repo);

            $em->persist($teacherSubject);
            $em->flush();
        }
        $this->addFlash('notice',
                        'Subjects added');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_teachers');
    }

    return $this->render(   'PIE10Bundle:Form:layout_commom_form.html.twig',
                            array(  'title'     => 'Add Subjects',
                                    'form'      =>  $form->createView() )
    );
}
```

and the ClassSubjectType is like below,

```
class ClassSubjectType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('subject',
                  EntityType::class,
                  array('class'         => 'PIE10Bundle:Subject',
                        'expanded'      => true,
                        'multiple'      => true,
                        'attr'          => array(   'class' => 'form-control',
                                                    'style' => 'margin:5px 0;')));

    $builder->add('Add Classes',
                      SubmitType::class,
                      array('attr'  =>  array('class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                                              'style' => 'margin:15px 0;')) );

}
}
```

So I need to know what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.